# InteractiveViewer RenderTransform object was given an infinite size during layout

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an `InteractiveViewer` widget inside `Stack` widget so basically the layout goes `Center > AspectRatio > GestureDetectot > Stack > InteractiveViewer`. The last bit is as follows:

```
Stack(
  fit: StackFit.expand,
  children: [
    InteractiveViewer(
      constrained: false,
      scaleEnabled: false,
      panEnabled: false,
      transformationController: _transformationController,
      child: SomeWidget()
    ),
  ],
)
```

So with this setup, I keep getting the error `RenderTransform object was given an infinite size during layout`, if I put the `SomeWidget()` outside (in place of `InteractiveViewer`), the error goes away, this has been driving me crazy for sometime and none of the answers on **SO** or google have managed to help me so far, any help will be highly appreciated or even point to the right direction where I would be able to find a solution for this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A lot of information is missing to reach a conclusion, for example in what context are these widgets inserted, what are the parameters of interactiveView, the data about SomeWideget (), to help in a more concrete analysis we need a mvp of this section where the error is reproduced.

Comment: @Chance I updated the question, although I don't understand what you mean by context and in this case lets say SomeWidget() is an image

Comment: Ok I didnt know the child matters, so the child is VideoPlayer

Comment: @Chance posted answer

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and therefore fixed it, posting answer just in case someone else encounters the same problem. Basically  put the `SomeWidget()` widget in a `SizedBox` with specific dimensions and it worked.